# Redirect custom Wordpress post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel

I've created a simple file which receives a post request and creates a post out of it. Code:

```
<?php 
require_once('wp-load.php'); // add wordpress functionality

if(isset($_POST['title'])) {

$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  '1',
        'post_name'     =>  'BBBBBBB',
        'post_title'        =>  $_POST['title'],
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'     =>  'post'
    )
);
}
?>
```

That works great, as expected.
The thing is, I want the user who clicks on this newly created post to get redirected to another site, let's just say I want him to get redirected to google. How would I go about achieving this?

[Entire Concept for those interested: A Post, created in Laravel, sends with a cronjob its data to my wordpress file, which creates a "fake wordpress post", upon which user who will click on it get redirected back to the site where the original post was created]
Thanks, as always.
greetings!

edit: I forgot to mention, this should only apply to posts which have been created via post request, or to be more specific, every post from now on.

Comment: Have you tried using something like wp_redirect('back-to-laravel.com?post_id_created=' . $post_id . '); You can feed it with query params from the fake post

Comment: That sounds like what I need. I have not found out yet, how to make it that the post itself executes that function. I have not worked with wordpress in quite a long time so things i would need to know are:a) How do i execute a function when viewing a post? b) Where do I put this function because i dont wanna ruin my post.php as the other posts need it.

Comment: I would say your best bet is to work with the WP HTTP API and create a custom API endpoint. It's a potentially big topic but it'll definitely put you on the right road. You don't need a separate file that bootstraps WP (requiring wp-load.php). Key is in the rest_api_init action and extending (or using as a reference) the WP_REST_Controller class. It's a bit much to go into in a comment, but you can put the function inside a custom route and hit it without it having any impact on other posts or site functionality.